# Why does object prototype methods have no caller in oop unlike in procedural programming

Tags: javascript, oop, function-prototypes, procedural-programming

If I have a procedural function calling another procedural function like this:

```
function awesome() {
    return arguments.callee.caller.name;
}
function ridiculous() {
    return awesome();
}
ridiculous();
```

Then I get back the caller named "ridiculous". But when I write it in oop-style, then the caller is null.

```
function myObj() {}
myObj.prototype.awesome = function() {
    return arguments.callee.caller.name;
}
myObj.prototype.ridiculous = function() {
    return this.awesome();
}
```

I wonder, why this happens and how to get back the caller anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key in the object and the name of the function isn't the same thing.

Take a look at my snippet:

```js
function myObj() {}
myObj.prototype.awesome = function awesome() {
    return arguments.callee.caller.name;
}
myObj.prototype.ridiculous = function ridiculous() {
    return this.awesome();
}

var o = new myObj();
console.log(o.ridiculous())
```

Comment: Silly me! After reading your answer it's completely obvious. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's because when declaring methods on prototype you should be using named functions.

such as:

```
function myObj() {}
myObj.prototype.awesome = function awesome() {
    return arguments.callee.caller.name;
}
myObj.prototype.ridiculous = function ridiculous() {
    return this.awesome();
}

myObj.prototype.ridiculous()
```